# Unable to run nightwatch JSON

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have been trying to run a simple test with Nightwatchjs and I keep running into issues.

I believe I have setup my JSON file correctly:

```
{
 "src_folder" : ["./smoketests"],
 "output_folder" : "./reports",

 "selenium" : {
 "start_process" : true,
 "start_session" : true,
 "server_path" : "M:/nightwatch/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar",
 "log_path" : false,
 "host" : "127.0.0.1",
 "port" : 4444,
 "cli_args" : {
  "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./lib/chromedriver.exe"
  }
 },

 "test_settings" : {
 "default" : {
  "launch_url" : "http://www.google.com/",
  "selenium_port" : 4444,
  "selenium_host" : "localhost",
  "silent" : true,
  "screenshots" : {
    "enabled" : false,
    "path" : "./screenshots/smoketests"
  }
 },
 "desiredCapabilities" : {
  "browserName" : "firefox",
  "javascriptEnabled" : true,
  "acceptSslCerts" : true
 },

 "chrome" : {
  "desiredCapabilities" : {
    "browserName" : "chrome",
    "javascriptEnabled" : true,
    "acceptSslCerts" : true
    }
   }
  }
}
```

and my test is pretty simple:

```
module.exports = {

beforeEach : function(browser) {
  browser.maximizeWindow();
 },

 'Test title' : function(browser)    {
  browser
  .url('http://www.google.com/')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
  .assert.title("Google")
  browser.end();
   }
  };
```

Yet, when I run the test:

```
nightwatch -c smoketests/homepage.json
```

I receive the following error:

```
M:\nightwatch>nightwatch -c projects/smoketests/homepage.json
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  6448 

C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\
runner\run.js:116
 var fullPaths = testSource.map(function (p) {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at module.exports.readPaths (C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\nightwatch\lib\runner\run.js:116:31)
at runner [as run] (C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nig
htwatch\lib\runner\run.js:182:10)
at Object.CliRunner.runner (C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\nightwatch\lib\runner\cli\clirunner.js:345:16)
at C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runne
r\cli\clirunner.js:321:12
at SeleniumServer.onStarted (C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\nightwatch\lib\runner\cli\clirunner.js:281:9)
at SeleniumServer.checkProcessStarted (C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\selenium.js:140:10)
at SeleniumServer.onStderrData (C:\Users\jomartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\selenium.js:120:8)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
```

Has anybody else encounter this issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out my initial issue. I had a syntax error in my "scr_folders" in my JSON file. After fixing it, my test seems to run fine.